# After an insert into the UITableView : custom the cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm using insertion into my UITableView with this :

```
 Skill * newSkill = [[Skill alloc] init];
    newSkill.name = @"Nouvelle compétence";
    newSkill.pathPicto = @"generic";
    [self.skills insertObject:newSkill atIndex:0];

    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
    [self.tableView
     insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath]withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
    [self.tableView endUpdates];
```

It works great but now I want that the inserted cell be editable.

I would like that the label "Nouvelle compétence" can be edited and override with another text, and I would change the label color but I don't know how as the cell is inserted automatically. Maybe with a specific method before inserting ??

Comment: You have to have a UITextField that can be "touched" and change its property on your Custom cells.

Comment: But I want only the inserted cell to be editable, not the others.

Comment: You can disable the textfield (hide it) when needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use UITextField instead of UILabel.
When you insert a new cell, set this UITextField's `enabled` property to `true`.

When loading all the other cells remember to set it to `false` to disable editing (the same cell maybe used at more than one place).

Comment: I don't know how to identify the cell which has been inserted.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood the question.

Comment: I've use UITextView instead of UILabel

Comment: In this case, maybe keep a separate variable to keep track of whether modify is enabled? If it is enabled, set the first cell to be editable in `tableViewWillDisplayCell:ForIndexPath:`. If it is not enabled, just set every cell to be disabled.